# Get difference in time between increments of two count metrics in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm working on a Grafana Dashboard with prometheus metrics.
I have a few counter metrics that describes, given a set of events, how many times each event happened.

What I would like to do is have a dashboard that represent the time passing between the occurrence of event1 (T1) and the occurrence of event2 (T2); basically T2-T1.

The idea would be to have an alarm that triggers when T2-T1 > Tmax.

Somebody knows if it's possible to define a query to obtain the desired result?

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by "metrics that describes, given a set of events, how many times each event happened" (and better yet pick minimal representative set of metrics and put into question)? And do you need to visualize this data, or your goal only to create alert rule?

Comment: Hi @markalex!
I have a finite state machine and I have for each state, a counter that increments when I reach one.
What I want is to know if it is possible and how, to get the time of transition from one state A to state B.
The dashboards could be some data that represent the percentile of time. The alarm would be helpful for cases that needs attention or manual operation. Hope it's clear

Answer (score 1):

If you have only counter for events and events are relatively often any visualization would be most likely flawed. Parallel execution and lack of traceability would be a reason for this.

If events relatively rare, I believe better approach would be to add metric providing timestamp (as value) and some kind of unique identifier of the process which produced event (as label). In that case traceability is quite obvious, an visualize events and delays would be matter of simple query like

```
custom_event_timestamp{event="A"} - ignoring(event) custom_event_timestamp{event="B"}
```

if timestamp metrics supplied (more or less) continuously, and

```
last_over_time(custom_event_timestamp{event="A"}[10m]) - ignoring(event) last_over_time(custom_event_timestamp{event="B"}[10m])
```

for case of metrics supplied once (like through pushgateway).

That being said, you could possibly (not tested!) try and imitate such "timestamp metric" through [recording rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/).

```yaml
  - name: last_event_timestamp
    rules:
    - record: timestamp:custom_event:increase
      expr: timestamp(custom_event - custom_event offset 10s >0)
```

and later use it for visualization as

```
last_over_time(timestamp:custom_event:increase{event="A"}[10m]) - ignoring(event) last_over_time(timestamp:custom_event:increase{event="B"}[10m])
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear suggestions

Comment: @OmarElMalak, If you are planing to try the recording rules suggestion, please left feedback if it worked afterwards.